# Query a many-to-many field django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have a model with a many-to-many field like this:

```
class BillingMonth(models.Model):
    month = models.IntegerField(min=1, max=12)

class BillingCycle(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    months_billed = models.ManyToManyField(BillingMonth)
```

Each BillingCycle (monthly, quarterly, etc) will get billed in one or more months.   The rental equipment model looks like this:

```
class RentalEquipment(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField()
    billing_cycle = models.ForeignKey(BillingCycle)
```

How do I find all RentalEquipment that should be billed on a given month?  This doesn't seem to work:

```
billing_month = BillingMonth(month=8)
RentalEquipment.objects.filter(billing_cycle__months_billed=billing_month)
```

Alternatively, is having a ManyToMany relationship overkill for the BillingCycle model?  Is there a better way to include an array of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can break out the query like so:

```
billing_month = BillingMonth(month=8)
billing_cycles = Billing_cycle.objects.filter(months_billed=billing_month)
equipment_needing_billing = RentalEquipment.objects.filter(billing_cycle__in=billing_cycles)
```

Comment: What is (are) the difference(s)/error(s) that you noticed in the two methods of yours?